# How to Compile iOS programs in Windows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've recently learned some basic Objective-C and have made a really simple "HelloWorld" application for development on iPhones (not through the AppStore, but Jailbreaked iPhones)

I've got my main.m file and Classes in my HelloWorld directory.

I have GNUStep Shell installed on my Windows Machine, the real question is:
How do I compile my HelloWorld Application so I can send it to my iOS device.

I really just want to get the compiled files and SSH it to my /Applications/ Directory to test it.

How can it be done? Thanks.

EDIT:

Alternatively, is there a way I can upload the SDK headers to my iPhone using SSH and compile my program on my iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it will be much more comfortable to use virtual machine with mac OS. In this way you will full development toolbox including debugger, leak tester and so on.